# list management python

Tags: python

I have extracted some url list and want to manipulate this list. Following is extracted list sample:

```
http://help.naver.com/service/svc_index.jsp?selected_nodeId=NODE0000000235
http://www.naver.com/rules/service.html
http://news.naver.com/main/principle.nhn
http://www.naver.com/rules/privacy.html
http://www.naver.com/rules/disclaimer.html
http://help.naver.com/claim_main.asp
http://news.naver.com/main/ombudsman/guidecenter.nhn?mid=omb
http://www.nhncorp.com/
http://www.nhncorp.com/
```

I want to extract only URLs that start with 'http://www.naver.com', so finally what I want list is following

```
http://www.naver.com/rules/privacy.html
http://www.naver.com/rules/disclaimer.html
http://www.naver.com/rules/service.html
```

How can I only extract what I want?

Comment: What exactly do you want?  You give an example answer, but I cannot figure out the question:  do you want just the static .html pages and not the dynamic answers?

Answer (score 6):

If your `old` list is contains all urls as strings you can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to filter them.

```
new = [url for url in old if url.startswith('http://www.naver.com')]
```

You *could* write it as a explicit loop, but it adds nothing but lines of code:

```
new = []
for url in old:
   if url.startswith('http://www.naver.com'):
       new.append( url )
```

If you planned on *removing* items from the original list while looping over it: Don't ever do that, it won't work. You can modify the original list instead with the same [LC](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
old[:] = [url for url in old if url.startswith('http://www.naver.com')]
```

Comment: If the OP really is a beginner show him the non-list comprehension equivalent too.  (Not that it's hard to derive but I think it's good to actually *see* the difference.)

Comment: hello, old[:] = [url for url in old if url.startswith('http://www.naver.com')]
this one is working well for me .
thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a [List Comprehension](http://www.diveintopython.org/native_data_types/mapping_lists.html).  These are a very powerful way to work with lists with Python.

By adding add an `if` to the list comprehension [you can filter the list](http://www.diveintopython.org/power_of_introspection/filtering_lists.html).

Assuming your URLs are stored in the variable `myurls`:

```
filteredurls = [url for url in myurls if url.startswith('http://www.naver.com')]
```

Comment: Naming your variable "list" in Python is a very bad practice :]

Answer (score 0):

```
urlList = [ ... ] # your list of urls
extractedList = [url for url in urlList if url.startswith('http://www.naver.com')]
```

Comment: @gnud: and then it's not being used ;)

Comment: Lol, I guess I was a bit in a hurry. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = []
for url in myListOfUrls:
    if 'http://www.naver.com' in url:
        result.append(url)
```

Comment: This is the non-list comprehension version.  Does it work by coincidence?  Could `http://www.naver.com` appear later on in a url?

Comment: @quamrana: `'http://www.naver.com'` could be anywhere in `url` according to this code

Comment: I did this to accommodate for leading whitespaces and other markups. The URL itself should "technically" not appear anywhere but at the start, so this code should not error.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget:  Could `'http://naver.com'` appear after a `?` in one of the urls?

Comment: I don't see why it would, unless we're talking about something like PHP scripts. But in that case, it would be allowed by my code

Comment: Hello all,
really thanks for many people's help!
i will try all method and will answer soon
thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested this alternative answer based on `filter()` but deleted it, I'll post it here again for completeness:

```
newList = filter(lambda url: url.startswith('http://www.naver.com'), oldList)
```

The list comprehension method seems faster though (and in my opinion, more readable):

```
$ python -m timeit -c "filter(lambda url: url.startswith('1'), map(str, range(100)))"
10000 loops, best of 3: 143 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -c "[ url for url in map(str, range(100)) if url.startswith('1') ]"
10000 loops, best of 3: 117 usec per loop
```